# My Stack Overflow flair username is trimmed

Tags: bug, feature-request, design, flair

I want to use the Stack Overflow flair and my username (which is also my real name) is trimmed. The last letter of my surname is missing.

Screenshot (in case the flair hopefully becomes fixed in the future):

> [image]

The actual generated Flair:

> [image]

Is it possible to make the font size dynamically smaller in case of longer username?

Is it possible to customize the flair in any way except the frame and background color i.e. optionally remove the profile picture or making the flair wider (through the parameters)?

- I don't want to change the username as I want to use my real name and surname.
- I don't want to change my real name or surname either.
- I don't want to shorten the username only to 'Nikolas' or 'Charalambidis'

Let's say I could, but it doesn't solve the problem somebody else might face.

**Important note:** It's odd the usernames can be 30 characters long while flair works only with usernames up to 20 characters (- [Scratte's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402775/my-stackoverflow-flair-name-is-trimmed?noredirect=1#comment807398_402775)).

Comment: I relate to having such a long name. But for me, normally it needs to be shaved by 3 or four characters.

Comment: You could shorten your nickname to "Charalambidis". But that, I expect, isn't really the point :)

Comment: @Scratte: I though about that :) I want to keep my online profile consistent (GitHub, FaceBook etc...). Moreover, I am sure I am not the only one who would face this issue and changing such name would be not an option. - what if **[this guy](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=uvuvwevwevwe%20onyetenyevwe%20ugwemuhwem%20osas)** decides to join the community? :)

Comment: I expect that guy would only show up as "uvuvwevwevwe onyeten", which is less than half ;) Though you can argue that the cut off has to be somewhere, at present that is 20 characters. It seems a bit odd though, since usernames can be 30 characters long. But.. if you don't get a fix for it, at least you can remove the space in your nickname and still keep all the important bits :)

Comment: That is the point! The username length is gapped at 30 while the flair works only up to 20. I have included this note to the question if you don't mind.

Comment: So, how do you propose the username is rendered, instead, in the same space? How would it render with 30 characters?

Comment: @Cerbrus By changing the font, I guess.

Comment: @Cerbrus: In the question: *"Is possible to make the font size dynamically smaller..."* ... and ... *"Is possible to customize the flair..."*.

Comment: What font could possibly allow for ***50%*** more characters in the same amount of space? As a front-end developer _"Just change the font"_ is a bit of a pet peeve. That doesn't magically make things fit. And even so, then it'd look silly for the large majority of usernames that aren't nearly as long.

Comment: @Cerbrus: As a back-end developer I have no idea. But how about optionally **remove the profile picture** or allowing to change the **width** of the flair?

Comment: A more sensible solution would be to allow the width to be set... Which you just edited into your comment :P

Comment: @Cerbrus: Agreed, one of my thoughts.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Try Νικόλας Χαραλαμπίδης

Comment: @MantaRei: A good trick as long as 'Ch' is equal to the Greek 'Χ' However, I am not Greek (not speaking that language) so I have no right to use these characters. :)

Comment: They could easily truncate with ellipsis (Nikolas Charalambi...) and have a tooltip with your full name, if that's a reasonable compromise. I'm assuming that in the places you use flair, you're using your full name elsewhere? IOW the flair is not your only form of id?

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike How to address the issue is ignored and remind myself without "unhelpful noise"?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis It is not ignored, it just hasn't been responded to yet. All [meta-tag:feature-requests] posts create an entry in the staff's work tracker automatically. They just don't have a lot of staff working on them, and the staff is shared across [meta-tag:bug] and other work, too.

Comment: Ironically we had a user complaining a few days ago that (among other things) the flair images had too much white space. This is the perfect example of why they need that much white space.